# non-static method sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-automation-framework

I am Using IntelliJ Idea 2016.3.4 and JDK 1.8. It has an inspection that claims the following:

> java: non-static method sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...) cannot be referenced from a static context

```
@Test(priority = 4)
public void requestSearchedISIN() {
    driver.get(CTACustomerRFQ.CustomerLanding_URL);
    customerRFQPage.typesearchedISIN(CTACustomerRFQ.ISIN);
    WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

I already tried below steps, but it didn't work

> File-->Project Structure-->ProjectSettings-->Project In "Project
>   Language level" field select "7-Diamonds, ARM, Multi-catch etc"

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebElement` is a class **type**. You need an **instance** of `WebElement`

Something like

```
//create the instance of the element you want to interact with
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.id(<your id goes here>));
//use that instance
yourElement.sendKeys("some text you want to send to your element");
```

**Why?:**

`sendKeys` is a `non-static` method, meaning it can only be called when you have an **instance** of the class it's in, in this case `WebElement`. `static` methods on the other hand, don't need an **instance** to be called.

Consider the situation to understand why the `Selenium` devs chose to make `sendKeys` and other methods that interact with a webelement `non-static`. Would it make sense to `click` a `WebElement` when that object isn't actually attached to an actual element yet? Of course not. This is why you can only use those methods after you have located the element and created an *instance*.

---

It looks like you're trying to script some keyboard commands to the overall page instead of trying to interact with the elements directly. Selenium `WebElement`s allow you to interact directly with an element, so you don't have to try to tab your way (Or press arrow keys) to the element you want to use.